# Check for composite unique index input via Request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest, laravel-5.1

I have a site that has multiple instances (companies).

Each company can add their own inventory and `unit` number must be unique within instance (company). But I want to allow same unit number per company. Therefore, `unit+ instance_id` needs to be unique. Is there a way to implement this check in Request rules?

The following rule checks if unit already exists in the inventory. I need to add check for `inventory.id AND inventory_instance_id`

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'unit' => 'unique:inventory|required|max:45',
        'comments' => 'sometimes|max:255'
    ];
}

public function messages() {
    return [
        'unit.unique' => 'Unit number already exists!',
        'unit.required' => 'Enter Unit Number!',
        'max' => ':attribute - Should not be longer than 255 symbols!'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unique` validation allows for many parameters. The syntax is roughly `unique:table,column,except,idColumn,whereN,valueN`.

The first parameter is the table, second is the field to be unique, third is an id to ignore, fourth is id column for the third parameter, and then the fourth and fifth (and six/seventh, etc...) allow you to specify additional where clauses for your unique validation. This is what you're looking for.

You can use the fourth and fifth parameters to specify that your unit must be unique within your specified instance id. Assuming your instance id is stored in `inventory.instance_id` and you have the value for that field in a variable called `$instanceId`, your rule would look something like:

```
public function rules() {
    $instanceId = 1;
    return [
        'unit' => 'unique:inventory,unit,NULL,id,instance_id,'.$instanceId.'|required|max:45',
        'comments' => 'sometimes|max:255'
    ];
}
```

As you may have guessed, one of your issues now is that your rule is dynamically generated. You will need to figure out a way to update your rule with the instance id you're checking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check this package: https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator

I think it solves your problem.

Comment: wondering if there is a 'workaround' without additional packages